# Cannot find module `mysql`

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and trying to learn it.

Here, I am trying to access mySQL database in nodejs.

I have install module for this using `npm install mysql` but I am not getting any folder for mysql in `node_modules` folder.
but I am not getting any error while installing mysql module from terminal.
because of this issue I am not able to use mysql module in program and I am getting error as

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/mysql.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: Try the following commands: $npm list; $npm list -g; Is mysql in either of those lists? It's worth noting that npm install without the -g global flag will install in the current working directory (where you probably want them if you're using require).

Comment: did you `cd` into your directory then did the `npm install`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often it helps to get a package.json in your directory and install from there. Try creating a file called `package.json` and filling it with the following content (you'll want this down the line anyway if you are creating a node project you are going to continue working with):

```
{
  "name": "PROJECT NAME",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "YOUR NAME",
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "2.x.x"
  }
}
```

Once this is in place, you can just run `npm install` and should see a `node_modules` folder created and populated with the mysql source. In the future if you want to add dependencies and have them saved to your `package.json` automatically, you can just run `npm install whatever --save`. Quite convenient!

Comment: steps helped me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you try to install new module, npm is looking for `node_modules` directory in current location, and if there is none, it's looking in parent directory, and so on.
If `node_module` is present somewhere there, your module will be installed there.
That's probably what happens in your case.

If you want to install mysql module in your present directory, just create empty `node_modules` directory where you want to install it.